# hive group by on one column and sum up on another columns with specific substrings

Tags: sql, hive

I have an output from the first select. It'd look like this.

```
david    iphone 13
david    iphone 14
david    galaxy 22
david    oneplus
frank    iphone 13 
frank    oneplus
macy     oneplus
```

I'm trying to get an output like this.

##### desired output

```
# name  apple samsung <-- not included in the output, but the column name to indicate what are the numbers
david    2  1 
frank    1  0 
macy     0  0
```

My script looks like this.

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN (tb.device LIKE '%iphone%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apple,
   SUM(CASE WHEN (tb.device LIKE '%galaxy%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS samsung
FROM (
SELECT 
   name, device
..
..
..
) tb 
GROUP BY name
```

The first select will generate `name, device` which was shown in the beginning. I'm trying to get the `desired output`, but it's not working. Any idea?

I tried as mentioned above.

Comment: this looks perfect. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm not getting the desired output. Keep getting an error "Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE ..."

Comment: paste the actual query

Comment: It looks like some system issue and not related to query. Pls check with your admin